# Unable to query Presto database using Dbvisuallizer- Error Executing Query

Tags: mysql, presto, dbvisualizer, presto-jdbc

We are trying to connect to presto using Dbvisualizer . and execute some queries . Catlog we are using is mysql .

- Presto is installed in the linux server . presto cli is working fine in the linux . Started presto in linux .
- Mysql is also installed in the linux machine . We are able to access mysql in windows using Dbvisualizer.
- Created a mysql connector catalog for Presto. Successful in querying data of mysql using Presto-cli
  as `presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog mysql --schema tutorials`

DBvisualizer is installed in the Windows machine . I'm able to access mysql and execute queries .
Presto also connected in Dbvisualizer . But we are unable to query data .
When we try to run a query . It is giving us Error Executing Query .

[image]

There is not much information available online , We dont know what we are missing here , Can Someone explain me the way to do this .
We need to execute queries from windows machine . we also tried from java code using jdbc jar . same exception

Added the Screenshot of Config.properties of the Presto Installation . Any property more to be added here?
[image]
. Any suggestion is appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Before I start diving in, Tarun, your ip address is showing still at the top of the image. Can you update the image to cover it?

Comment: What type of authentication are you using for your Presto cluster?

Comment: Hi Brain Olsen , Thanks for pointing out the visible ip .There are two ways i have tried connecting to Presto . 1.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_presto/apache_presto_jdbc_interface.htm.    2.Using Dbvisualizer , using presto database driver in the dbvisualizer to connect . If you are talking about installing Password Authenticator in the Presto instance https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/password-authenticator.html . I have not installed it .

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't installed any way to authenticate to use Presto. The authentication that exists on your MySQL instance is not used to authenticate users that access your Presto cluster.

There is a [critical security vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-15087) in Presto where "authenticated users can bypass authorization checks by directly accessing internal APIs". This has only been resolved in the [Trino (formerly PrestoSQL)](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html) distribution so I recommend you use Trino if you plan on running a secured cluster in production.

Your options on Trino are, [LDAP authenticator](https://trino.io/docs/current/security/ldap.html), [Password authenticator](https://trino.io/docs/current/security/password-file.html), and [Kerberos authenticator](https://trino.io/docs/current/security/server.html) (don't recommend unless you already use Kerberos). Configure these first before trying to use SSL/TLS on your server.

You can also find help you with any further questions for setting up a secure cluster on the [Trino slack channel](https://trino.io/slack.html).